# Метка [проект] не нужна

Tags: предложение, метки, удаление-метки

Есть метка [проект](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82) (40 вопросов) с таким описанием:

> Данную метку использовать для вопросов связанных с проектом, как совместной и запланированной деятельности для достижения определенной цели. В разработке программного обеспечения проект представляет собой набор файлов и ресурсов, используемых при разработке приложения или службы. Это универсальная метка, которую следует использовать, когда более конкретные метки недоступны.

Это слишком общая метка, и к тому же её лепят где попало. Её надо сжечь.

Туда же и метку [проекты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%8b) (13 вопросов).

Comment: Ну вообще это метку можно использовать в том случае если есть вопрос про структуру проекта.

Comment: Признак ненужной метки - если её нельзя использовать самостоятельно без других меток. Вопрос - мы можем понять что имеется ввиду по одной лишь метке [проект]? Мне кажется нет. @NNL993 Ваш пример скорее действителен лишь для метки [структура-проекта]. Примерно теми же свойствами обладает метка [программа] - сама по себе она бесполезна, а вот [структура-программы] уже получше.

Answer (score 2):

Не нужно сжигать. Вместо этого, предлагаю поправить описание:

> Проект - набор файлов и ресурсов, используемых при разработке приложения или службы. Используйте метку только для вопросов по работе с проектами в системах сборки или IDE.

Вполне нормально использовать эту метку для классификации вопросов, которые относятся к понятию "проект" в системах сборки. Это позволяет, например, поискать по меткам "С++" и "проект", чтобы вывести вопросы по проектам в С++. Из вопросов по управлению проектами, или просто расплывчатых вопросов типа "что делать с проектом на Sourceforge", эту метку нужно будет удалить. Они либо кандидаты на закрытие, либо им нужны другие метки.

> и к тому же её лепят где попало

Это недостаточная причина. Многие новички не понимают, как работают система меток, и  вводят в метки, что пришло в голову. Более опытные участники могут поправить метки за них. Сжигаться должны в первую очередь метки, которые представляют серьезную проблему и которые достаточно популярны и поэтому часто попадаются на глаза.

**Добавлено:** [Применил новое описание](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/938692/3).

Comment: А ещё нужно к метке [tag:проект] добавить синоним [tag:проекты].

Comment: Если уж ставите [управление-проектами], то синоним с [project-management] закажите ;-)

Comment: @Kromster Лучше снесу русский вариант. От этих меток обеих толку мало, они нужны лишь, чтобы куда-то деть сомнительные вопросы.